# Determine intersection between a circle and list of data points

Tags: manipulate, intersection

I have radius to draw circle using formulation below:

```
rhom = 0.262707;
circle = Table[{rhom*Cos[Theta*Degree], rhom*Sin[Theta*Degree]}, {Theta, 1, 360}] // N;
```

I also have 2 lists of data points:

```
A={{-0.104703,0.264857},{-0.236896,0.0575121},{-0.387596,-0.136798},{-0.555529,-0.316423},{-0.739274,-0.479839},{-0.937274,-0.625657},{-1.14785,-0.752641}};
B={{1.27548,0.237216},{0.406627,-0.105033},{-0.456116,-0.462393},{-1.31249,-0.834755}};
```

How to find the intersection point as shown in the figure below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
a = Interpolation[A];
b = Interpolation[B];
ptA = {t, a[t]} /. FindRoot[a[t]^2 + t^2 - rhom^2, {t, -.2}];
ptB = {t, b[t]} /. FindRoot[b[t]^2 + t^2 - rhom^2, {t, 0}];
{ptA, ptB}

(* {{-0.261721, 0.0227437}, {0.0231856, -0.261682}} *)

Show[Plot[a[t], {t, -1, -0.1}], Plot[b[t], {t, -1, 1}], 
 Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, rhom], PointSize[0.02], Red, 
   Point[{ptA, ptB}]}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in different ways. There is the more basic math way using those conventional  `FindRoot`, `NSolve` etc. I show here a method using a comparatively newer function in the family named `MeshRegion`.

1. Generate a [MeshRegion](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion.html) from the points giving you `circle`, and the lines `a` and `b` as 2D geometric boundaries.
2. Then we take respective [intersection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection.html) between those objects, giving us 2D points that we are seeking.

So code is:

```
circle = MeshRegion[circle, Line[Range[Length@circle]~Join~{1}]];
{a, b} = MeshRegion[#, Line[Range@Length@#]] & /@ {A, B};
{ptA, ptB} = MeshCoordinates@RegionIntersection[##] & @@@ {{circle , a}, {circle , b}}
```

> {{{-0.261419,0.0258928},{-0.12692,0.230009}},{{0.030195,-0.260956},{0.163173,-0.205875}}}

You can see the found points graphically.

```
Show[circle , a, b, Graphics@{Orange, PointSize@.01, Point /@ ptA}, 
 Graphics@{Green, PointSize@.01, Point /@ ptB}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Also note that the more number of points you have to discretely represent your geometric objects, the more accurate this solution will be.

Comment: I try use it on Version 10.3 but it does not work as your illustration above. I have error on code {ptA,ptB}=MeshCoordinates@RegionIntersection[##] & @@@ {{circle , a}, {circle , b}}. Please give me advice, @PlatoManiac

Comment: The function `MeshRegion ` is available from version 11, it will not work in 10.3. The other answer will work on 10.3.